# Permission denied appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets

I am trying to read google spreadsheets and my code is runing successfully in  python script but when i try to write this code in google app engine then it will give this error

```
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

File "/var/www/html/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py", line 679, in bind
raise _SystemExceptionFromAppError(e)
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

please give me help me

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed some kind of permission, please make sure to have enabled Google Drive API. Also make sure to have the credentials you use to attempt this with Project Editor role.

I found a step by step tutorial that is attempting to do something similar to you. Have a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2).

I would also attempt to change the port from 0 to something higher than 1024, it seems that accounts that don't have elevated permissions cannot use ports lower than the previous one. See if that works for you. [Info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24001186/11928097)